# bq load from cloud storage slow

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload several files to BigQuery from Cloud Storage. Files are about 3.8GB compressed (16GB uncompressed) but the job took 12402s before I got Bad Character error.

```
Job cloudsql-sigma:job_9e4f13da43b649fe86b6410887c8d2c7

  Job Type    State      Start Time      Duration   Bytes Processed   
  load       FAILURE   27 Aug 12:27:21   3:24:17                     

Errors encountered during job execution. Too many errors encountered. Limit is: 0.
Failure details:
  - Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered. Rest of file not processed.
```

Why is it taking so long?

Comment: 3 hours and 24 minutes, for a 4GB file.  That's about 2mb/s, about the speed of consumer grade DSL.  is your internet just slow?

Comment: It's really not. Just reached 234Mbps in upload with speedtest.net

Comment: Well, aside from obvious practical things like that, I'd say I can't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently an open bug where mistakenly believe that some compressed files are malformed. -- we get an ascii 0 at the end of the file and fail. We retry twice, so what is really happening is that we're processing the file 3 times, each one taking about an hour. 16gb in 68 minutes is about 4MB / sec -- this is slower than I'd expect, but not terribly.

If you want the import to be faster, I'd suggest breaking it up smaller pieces, and listing those files separately in the job. They will be processed in parallel.

In the mean time, I'll try to get the fix for the ascii 0 at the end of the file into this week's release of BigQuery.

Comment: Just an FYI the 'Bad Ascii character' has been fixed internally. It will likely be in next week's release. It only happens when the uncompressed file is > 4GB.